# "Invalid character" in enum declaration

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums, eslint

I'm trying to create a enum in TypeScript, but I am getting a error:

[image: My Enum]

The error is:

> - error TS1127: Invalid character.

The version of typescript that I am using in my package.json `^4.1.3`.
Here is a print of all my package.json:

[image]

As you can see the VS Code is using the same version:

[image]

Could anyone help me with that?

Comment: [Please consider replacing or supplementing images of code or errors with plain text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).  And also consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Answer (score 0):

You should copy the code from somewhere and paste it. While pasting, hidden invalid character was added, and that's why the error occurs. Try to write the code from scratch and see if it works.